# Analog of the Pauli vector for $SU(4)$

Tags: quantum-information, group-theory, representation-theory, spinors, density-operator

In quantum mechanics and representation theory, it is well known that the Pauli matrices transform as a vector due to the special relationship between $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$. For example, suppose we have a single qubit; then $U\vec{v}\cdot\vec{\sigma}U^{\dagger} = \left(Q_{U}\vec{v}\right)\cdot\vec{\sigma}$, where $U$ is an element of $SU(2)$ and $Q_{U}$ is the associated $SO(3)$ rotation. I'm curious to learn if this generalizes to larger quantum mechanical systems.

Here is an example: suppose we have two qubits, and now let $U$ be an element of $SU(4)$. For an arbitrary state $\rho$ of the two qubits, we might be interested in calculating $U\rho U^{\dagger}$. Of course, $\rho$ has a decomposition in terms of the Pauli matrices, i.e., there are coefficients $a_{\mu\nu}$ such that $\rho = \sum_{\mu,nu}a_{\mu\nu}\sigma_{\mu}\otimes\sigma_{\nu}$, so we just need to think about $U\left(\sigma_{\mu}\otimes\sigma_{\nu}\right)U^{\dagger}$. Is there an analogous statement in this context to the one that holds for one qubit?

Comment: Two qubits won't live in SU(4).  They will live in a compound rep of SU(2).